# Retrofit/GSON: how to handle response with both types: JSON object and JSON array?

Tags: gson, retrofit

my server team defines a terrible reponse, which may be a json object like `{key1=value1, key2=value2}`, and may be a json array like `[{key3=value3, key4=value4}, {key3=value3a, key4=value4a}]`.

the two types has logical relationship as follows: for a single API, the server would:

- send JSON object if there's some error, or
- send JSON array if there's valid data.

i cannot tell them to change this because this response is used by other ends like PC and iOS.

so what should i do with this four-letter-word-ing response? i use retrofit for network and GSON for response deserialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`JsonParser`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) to get [`JsonElement`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) from string
- Determine type (e.g. [`JsonArray`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html) or [`JsonObject`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html)) of this `JsonElement` (via [`JsonElement::isJsonArray`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#isJsonArray--) and [`JsonElement::isJsonObject`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#isJsonObject--))
- Parse result using [`Gson::fromJson`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-com.google.gson.JsonElement-java.lang.Class-)

```
static class Entity {
    String name;
    // other fields
}

static class Error {
    String errorName;
    // other fields
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // no error
    String jsonString = "[{'name': 'one'}, {'name': 'two'}]";
    // error
    // String jsonString = "{'errorName': 'Not Found'}";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
    if (jsonElement.isJsonArray()) {
        // no error
        Entity[] entities = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Entity[].class);
        System.out.println(entities[0].name);
    } else if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
        // error
        Error error = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Error.class);
        System.out.println(error.errorName);
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Server response is not jsonElement array or jsonElement object");
    }
}
```